# JSON Parsing in Android

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

I have searched alot on JSON Parsing in Android, but couldn't quite convinced. Actually got a brief idea but not so clear yet regarding JSON Parsing.

How to implement the JSON Parsing in the Application?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a very simple JSON String

```
{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}
```

In order to get values for it use `JSONObject` like this :

```
JSONObject json_obj=new JSONObject(your json string);
String value1=json_obj.getString("key1");
String value2=json_obj.getString("key2");
```

This is a slightly complex json string

```
[{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"},{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}]
```

In order to extract values from this use `JSONArray`

```
JSONArray jArray=new JSONArray(your json string);
for(int i=0;i<(jArray.length());i++)
{
    JSONObject json_obj=jArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String value1=json_obj.getString("key1");
    String value2=json_obj.getString("key2");
}
```

Hope this helps a bit...........

Answer (score 3):

See: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html

Primarily, you'll be working with [JSONArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html) and [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html).

Simple example:

```
    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        int someInt = json.getInt("someInt");
        String someString = json.getString("someString");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Failed to load from JSON: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also check out Google's GSON library [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).  The GSON user guide [here](http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide/) has some useful examples to help get you started.  I've found GSON to be simple and powerful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `org.json` package, bundled in the SDK.

See here: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONTokener.html

Comment: "JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);"

Comment: What the "(jsonString)" is for in the above line.

Comment: @david - this is the string containing the JSON-encoded information.

Answer (score 1):

One more choice: use Jackson.

Simple usage; if you have a POJO to bind to:

```
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); // reusable
  MyClass value = mapper.readValue(source, MyClass.class); // source can be String, File, InputStream
  // back to JSON:
  String jsonString = mapper.writeValue(value);
```

to a Map:

```
  Map<?,?> map = mapper.readValue(source, Map.class);
```

or to a Tree: (similar to what default Android org.json package provides)

```
  JsonNode treeRoot = mapper.readTree(source);
```

and more examples can be found at http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes.

Benefits compared to other packages is that it is lightning fast; very flexible and versatile (POJOs, maps/lists, json trees, even streaming parser), and is actively developed.