# Facebook json parsing in Android

Tags: android, json

How do I parse the following json returned from Facebook? I have tried by searching on Internet, but I failed. Please help me.

```
{"data":
    [{
        "id":"100001746392225_137743246275036",
        "from":{"name":"Narasimha Kolla",
            "id":"100001746392225"
      },
      "picture":"http:\/\/platform.ak.fbcdn.net\/www\/app_full_proxy.php?app=151044809337&v=1&size=z&cksum=4cd0a75d9fd95daf93788baadc219c63&src=http%3A%2F%2Ffacebook.fishville.static.zynga.com%2Fproduction%2Fassets%2Ffeedforms%2FFV_giveFishLoveV2_90x90.png",
      "link":"http:\/\/apps.facebook.com\/fishville\/track.php?creative&cat=love_fish&subcat&vtype=shortfeed&key=926ee25f373cf3246301de747fda493c%24%24ccF%28NVVW31sAM.ZUMQU50Q%29k%21pKUPyzJOBG2V%29_-akrU9kGoB3%2C8&next=http%3A%2F%2Fapps.facebook.com%2Ffishville%2Freward.php%3FfrHost%3D100001746392225%26frId%3Df9adb5b4b77c36e11168b38e98b90f31%26frType%3DFriendReward_ILoveMyFishV2%26key%3D926ee25f373cf3246301de747fda493c%24%24ccF%28NVVW31sAM.ZUMQU50Q%29k%21pKUPyzJOBG2V%29_-akrU9kGoB3%2C8%26appRef%3DAchievements%7C%7Cshortstory%7C%7CFriendReward_ILoveMyFishV2",
      "name":"Narasimha has given Love to their Fish and has some Love left over to give to their friends!",
      "description":"Narasimha has extra Love to share with their friends to help them unlock exclusive LOVE ITEMS!",
      "icon":"http:\/\/photos-b.ak.fbcdn.net\/photos-ak-snc1\/v43\/9\/151044809337\/app_2_151044809337_7378.gif",
      "actions":
            [{
                "name":"Comment",
                "link":"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/100001746392225\/posts\/137743246275036"
             },
             {
                "name":"Like",
                "link":"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/100001746392225\/posts\/137743246275036"
             },
             {
                "name":"Get some Love!",
                "link":"http:\/\/apps.facebook.com\/fishville\/track.php?creative=&cat=love_fish&subcat=&vtype=shortfeed&key=926ee25f373cf3246301de747fda493c$$ccF(NVVW31sAM.ZUMQU50Q)k!pKUPyzJOBG2V)_-akrU9kGoB3,8&next=reward.php%3FfrHost%3D100001746392225%26frId%3Df9adb5b4b77c36e11168b38e98b90f31%26frType%3DFriendReward_ILoveMyFishV2%26key%3D926ee25f373cf3246301de747fda493c%24%24ccF%28NVVW31sAM.ZUMQU50Q%29k%21pKUPyzJOBG2V%29_-akrU9kGoB3%2C8%26appRef%3DAchievements%7C%7Cshortstory%7C%7CFriendReward_ILoveMyFishV2"
             }],
             "privacy":
                 {
                    "description":"Everyone",
                    "value":"EVERYONE"
                 },
             "type":"link",
             "created_time":"2010-10-28T17:45:20+0000",
             "updated_time":"2010-10-28T17:45:20+0000",
             "attribution":"FishVille"
          },
          {
             "id":"100001746392225_171377042878314",
             "from":
                {
                    "name":"Narasimha Kolla",
                    "id":"100001746392225"
                },
                "picture":"http:\/\/platform.ak.fbcdn.net\/www\/app_full_proxy.php?app=151044809337&v=1&size=z&cksum=3db213d45c46a43c0520f0f1388e65c0&src=http%3A%2F%2Ffacebook.fishville.static.zynga.com%2Fproduction%2Fassets%2Ffeedforms%2FFV_lonelySeaTurtle_90x90.jpg%3Frev%3D83517",
                "link":"http:\/\/apps.facebook.com\/fishville\/track.php?creative&cat=lonely_creature&subcat=seaTurtle&vtype=shortfeed&key=a2a0d5df9d89a1ccafe9019f3d277a9f%24%24ccF%28NVVW31sAM.ZUMQU50Q%29k%21pKUHyY-slQo5yojg4R%2Cc%281N4ne8vSnwnL.C2v_ixbs&next=http%3A%2F%2Fapps.facebook.com%2Ffishville%2Flonelycreature.php%3Fowner_id%3D100001746392225%26lonely_creature_mission_id%3D5%26lonely_creature_mission_name%3DseaTurtle%26lonely_creature_sig%3D5c1029fe6c2f7f3f6117de8a9262277b",
                "name":"Narasimha found a scared Sea Turtle washed up on the beach! Oh no!",
                "description":"Narasimha was taking care of their fish when they discovered a poor little Sea Turtle far from home in FishVille. This little tyke got caught in a strong current and washed up on the beach! He would love to get back in the water. ",
                "icon":"http:\/\/photos-b.ak.fbcdn.net\/photos-ak-snc1\/v43\/9\/151044809337\/app_2_151044809337_7378.gif",
                "actions":
                    [{
                        "name":"Comment",
                        "link":"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/100001746392225\/posts\/171377042878314"
                    },
                    {
                        "name":"Like",
                        "link":"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/100001746392225\/posts\/171377042878314"
                    },
                    {
                        "name":"Adopt the Sea Turtle!",
                        "link":"http:\/\/apps.facebook.com\/fishville\/track.php?creative=&cat=lonely_creature&subcat=seaTurtle&vtype=shortfeed&key=a2a0d5df9d89a1ccafe9019f3d277a9f$$ccF(NVVW31sAM.ZUMQU50Q)k!pKUHyY-slQo5yojg4R,c(1N4ne8vSnwnL.C2v_ixbs&next=lonelycreature.php%3Fowner_id%3D100001746392225%26lonely_creature_mission_id%3D5%26lonely_creature_mission_name%3DseaTurtle%26lonely_creature_sig%3D5c1029fe6c2f7f3f6117de8a9262277b"
                    }],
                "privacy":
                    {"des
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This post may be usefull:
[JSON Parsing in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706515/json-parsing-in-android/3708997#3708997)
Can you tell me which library are you using for facebook?