# multi JSONarray Problem

Tags: java, android, json

i got this JSONArray but i cant figure out how to put it in a listview. i figured out the ArrayAdapter but is doesnt give me the right result

```
[{"id":"1","name":"Joris","sex":"1","birthyear":"1987"},{"id":"2","name":"bjorn","sex":"1","birthyear":"1987"},{"id":"3","name":"Mel","sex":"0","birthyear":"1992"},{"id":"4","name":"Peter","sex":"1","birthyear":"1955"},{"id":"5","name":"Geer","sex":"1","birthyear":"1979"}]
```

this is my result on the phone in a list after using ArrayAdapter. 
Can somebody help me?

```
{"id":"1","name":"Joris","sex":"1","birthyear":"1987"}
{"id":"2","name":"bjorn","sex":"1","birthyear":"1987"}
{"id":"3","name":"Mel","sex":"0","birthyear":"1992"}
{"id":"4","name":"Peter","sex":"1","birthyear":"1955"}
{"id":"5","name":"Geer","sex":"1","birthyear":"1979"}
```

Comment: what do you want to put in list view, i mean name, sex, birthyear etc?????

Comment: Based on the title of the question, do you think yo have a multi-dimensional array?  You do not.  You have an array of objects.

Comment: ok that is one thing i needed to know thats its not a multi array. but i only want the values after ":"-sign (dont know english word). So the real values. This is what came out of a mysql-db from my website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how you moved round it, but if would have done it this way.

The string you have is a collection of JSON objects, it's JSON array in terms of Java, so first step would be to parse that array and get each row in an ArrayList. This ArrayList shall be ArrayList of String[], where each row shall be an array containing id, sex, birthyear etc.

You can check this post for parsing JSON: 
[JSON Parsing in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706515/json-parsing-in-android/3708997#3708997)

Next step would be to create a custom listAdapter so that I can pass my created ArrayList and fetch elements from it and display in whatever way I want.

Comment: yep i know the last step. but thanx for the url.

Answer (score 1):

This [json parsing in java example](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/257-how-to-parse-json-in-java/) can help