# android, iterate over stringbuilder json?

Tags: android, json, stringbuilder

So my webservice returns a bunch of JSONObjects, which is turned into a string by my stringbuilder.

```
[{"DateID":"2011-02-01","DateName":"februari 2011","IntName":1102,"Consumption":172,"Temperature":null},{"DateID":"2011-01-01","DateName":"januari 2011","IntName":1101,"Consumption":316,"Temperature":null}]
```

How can I get this String to be iterable så I can get all the name/values inside? I've tried all the examples I found here but I only get the first objecxt or no object at all (since JSONObjects can't start with a '[' char).

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, as soon as I posted I found this great example:
[JSON Parsing in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706515/json-parsing-in-android/3708997#3708997)

It's all in the JSONArray of course..