# How to parse data in webview

Tags: javascript, json, ios7

my web view is loaded with below data can any one tell me how to get value of "updated_at" in below webview data.

```
{
    "status": "marked paid",
    "orderstatus": {
        "status": "ordered and paid",
        "created_at": "2014-07-21T04:17:16.820909",
        "updated_at": "2014-07-21T04:19:25.303492",
        "order": {
            "information": [
                {
                    "removed_products": {
                        "both": [],
                        "right": [],
                        "left": []
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = {
    "status": "marked paid",
    "orderstatus": {
        "status": "ordered and paid",
        "created_at": "2014-07-21T04:17:16.820909",
        "updated_at": "2014-07-21T04:19:25.303492",
        "order": {
            "information": [
                {
                    "removed_products": {
                        "both": [],
                        "right": [],
                        "left": []
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
};

var updated_at = obj.orderstatus.updated_at;
```

Comment: but how take above data from webview.

Comment: [JSON Parsing in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706515/json-parsing-in-android)